# Pandas `read_sql_query` with decimal data type

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, sqldatatypes, read-sql

I'm trying to use `read_sql_query()` to read a query from  MySQL database, one of the field in the database, its type is `decimal(28,5)`, I want to use `dtype=` parameter to have full control of the datatypes, but seems like pandas can't recognise `Decimal` type:

```
from decimal import *

dtypes = {
        'id': 'Int64',
        'date': 'datetime64',
        'value': Decimal
    }

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, mysql_engine, dtype=dtypes, coerce_float=False)
```

This will give me an error `TypeError: dtype '<class 'decimal.Decimal'>' not understood`

So if I don't specify the type for field `value`:

```
dtypes = {
        'id': 'Int64',
        'date': 'datetime64'
    }

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, mysql_engine, dtype=dtypes, coerce_float=False)
```

This works fine, if I print out the data type `print(type(df['value'][0]))`, this will show me `<class 'decimal.Decimal'>`, but is there a way that I can specify the type of field `value` to be decimal in the Python code? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try `np.float64`? Or do you specific want the `Decimal`

Comment: Hi @Erfan I don't want `float` type, I only want to keep it as decimal.